# How to create hashmap containing reference to another hashmap's element?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a struct containing two hashmaps - one with some value, and one with reference to another hashmap's element. Here is my code.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo;
struct Bar<'s>(&'s Foo);

struct MyStruct<'a> {
    first : HashMap<&'a str, Foo>,
    second : HashMap<&'a str, Bar<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn new() -> MyStruct<'a> {
        let mut result = MyStruct {
            first : HashMap::new(),
            second : HashMap::new(),
        };
        match result.first.get("") {
            Some(t) => { result.second.insert("", Bar(t)); },
            None => {},
        }
        result
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

and this code fails to compile with following error :

> error: `result.first` does not live long enough

I think this problem is related to lifetime, but I can't clearly explain what is wrong.

Could anybody explain what is happening and how to solve this error?

P.S. struct `Foo` and `Bar` are from library, so I can't modify these structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed related to ownership/borrowing/lifetimes.

In general, in Rust, it is not possibly to (safely) take a reference in a sibling attribute; therefore having `.second` point into `.first` is impossible.

However, even if you separated this in two structures, you will still run into problems because taking a reference into a `HashMap` borrows it (which means that as long as the reference lives, modifying the `HashMap` is forbidden), which is probably not what you wish for.

This last hurdle can be avoided, in this case, by simply sharing the memory; for example, having both `HashMap` using a `Rc<X>` value instead of `X` and `&'a X` respectively...

... however this will not help with your particular question given the `Foo` and `Bar<'a>` types.

You could change your structure into:

```
struct MyStruct<'a, 'b> {
    first: HashMap<&'a str, &'b Foo>,
    second: HashMap<&'a str, Bar<'b>>,
}
```

and then maintain the actual `Foo` instances elsewhere. A possibility if you need to allocate those `Foo` while maintaining the `HashMap` is to use arena allocation such as [`Arena<Foo>`](https://libraries.io/cargo/typed-arena).

Comment: Thank you for explanation! But I still have some problems. I added `Vec` to `MyStruct`, and tried to save `Foo` to that vector. But when I try to save reference of vector element to hashmap, I get same error. Why can't I use` Vec` for this problem, and which type should I use?(`Arena` type was suggested, but I'm unfamilliar with this library, and I prefer standard libraries) Playground link is here : https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=683bcdaca275e1d0c47c&version=stable

Comment: @Yang, please read the answer carefully again. Creating another `Vec` or `HashMap` or whatever inside *the same structure* won't work. You need to store `Foo`s elsewhere, outside of `MyStruct`.

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev Oh. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I think my problem is solved. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Yang: The `Arena` type was suggested instead of `Vec` specifically because `Arena` guarantees that you can objects to the `Arena` while keeping references into the `Arena`; `Vec` does not offer such guarantees. And yes, the `Arena` need be outside `MyStruct` because sibling borrows are not possible in safe Rust.